# Postgres & docker os disk cache

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using `docker-compose` to run my database container that has fairly small memory limit (using `mem_limit` setting).

Will the docker host disk cache be used (no mem limit) by the postgres container, or should I make sure the container has enough free memory for disk caching?

*Using Debian 4.9.246-2 linux host*